# sunspot_rails not re-indexing model after save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot, sunspot-rails

I have a model which deploys a delayed job that updates some of its attributes. The model is declared "searchable"...

```
searchable do
  text :content, :stored => true  
end
```

... which I thought would re-index after a save.  On testing, this doesn't seem to be the case. If I run: `rake sunspot:reindex`, then everything works as expected.  What could be causing this issue?

Comment: could you add some better keywords to this questions so it gets better reach?

Comment: I don't think this question is very well phrased, nor are the solutions. For one, the user obviously is using `sunspot_rails`, not just 'sunspot'. For two, the Answers suggested discuss things that are moot because of sunspot_rails's default sunspot settings.

Comment: I'm also interested in a rspec test for model commits, to make sure it's working.

Comment: I'm having this problem as well. It worked in development, but it's not working in production with delayed_jobes.

Answer (score 20):

As mentioned by Jason, you can call `Sunspot.commit_if_dirty` to issue a commit from your client.

From the server configuration side, another approach would be to set the `autoCommit` property in your `solrconfig.xml` to automatically issue commits when there have been changes made to your index. A `maxTime` of 60000 ms (one minute) should suffice for most sites.

Using `autoCommit` is probably the wiser choice in production applications, where a high volume of commits can easily impact your Solr server's performance. In fact, it's a good practice with Sunspot to *disable* its `auto_commit_after_request option` when your site starts getting a decent amount of updates.

Lastly, `autoCommit` has the advantage of being able to set it and forget it.

At [Websolr](http://websolr.com/), our default is to ignore client-issued commits in favor of `autoCommit`.

Comment: the question is actually about the `sunspot_rails` plugin, not vanilla sunspot.

Comment: Hi nessur, not sure what point you're trying to make here. sunspot_rails is little more than a light wrapper to hook Sunspot into Rails models and controllers. Besides which, this question boils down to issuing commits, which you can issue from `curl` for all the client matters.

Comment: The question asks about 'auto-commit' functionality, and this very 'light wrapper' adds to Sunspots' base functionality, so it's all too relevant which gem a user has installed. Undocumented features make the world go round, and the average novice might be intrigued to learn that sunsport_rails installs a controller hook that by default commits any pending changes to the solr index.

Answer (score 8):

The index will only reflect changes after `Sunspot.commit` is called. This happens automatically when you run `rake sunspot:reindex`.

Sunspot's Rails plugin also has a `auto_commit_after_request` config option which will call `Sunspot.commit_if_dirty` after every request but this will not be triggered by your background processes.

Your best bet is to call `Sunspot.commit_if_dirty` after as the last thing in your delayed job.

Comment: (repeating myself) The question is actually about the `sunspot_rails` plugin, not vanilla sunspot.

Comment: why best bet is ```Sunspot.commit_if_dirty``` better than ```Sunspot.commit``` ?

Comment: If I recall correctly, `Sunspot.commit` will always flushes to disk and starts a new searcher instance even when nothing has changed. `Sunspot.commit_if_dirty` will only do that work if a change has been made.

Answer (score 6):

I had the exact same problem as you - when I was testing my search functionality sunspot would never issue a commit to solr.  If I manually call Sunspot.commit everything works.  I fiddled around with auto_commit_after_request, but this is true by default so it shouldn't make a different.

So after some more investigation I found that Sunspot won't issue a commit automatically unless the change is made in the context of a web request.  If you're doing a change from a test or a background job you have to call Sunspot.commit manually.