# Solr reindex with associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, solr

I have the following code in my Model:

```
has_many :links
 searchable do
    text :name, :as => :name_textp
    integer :membership_ordering
    text :business_description, :stored => true
    text :tags do
      tags.map(&:name)
    end
    text :links_name do
      company_links.map(&:name)
    end    
    text :links_description do
      company_links.map(&:description)
    end
    text :links_tags do
      links.map(&:tags_text) 
    end
  end
```

When for some reason I update the model, Solr automatically add the change to the index. But when I update `links` , it seems it doesn't until I manually call the sunspot:solr:reindex. I also added the following code to the association:

```
  searchable do
    text :name
    text :description
    text :tags_text
  end
```

But I can't get it work. What else do I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

have you been installing solr from scratch or with [bundle install command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15742142/solr-with-rails-rake-sunspotreindex-is-not-working)
Please have a look to this procedure, I think that will make works your ruby / solr configuration.
Prefere to launch solr with :

```
bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:start
bundle exec rake sunspot:reindex
```

Enjoy :)

**UPDATE 6/06 1H49 BRT**
Do you have set autocommit in your [solrconfig.xml](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrConfigXml):

```
<autoCommit> 
  <maxDocs>10000</maxDocs>
  <maxTime>20000</maxTime>
</autoCommit>
```

**UPDATE 6/06 9H41 BRT**
Please take a look a this post: [sunset not reindexing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3632278/sunspot-rails-not-re-indexing-model-after-save) it seems to be a common issue.
Can be overpassed by performing a commit.
As [dzone](http://www.dzone.com/snippets/install-and-test-solrsunspot) says :

> you will need regular reindexing with sunspot.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yes it works, but what I want is to reindex solr without using rake sunspot:reindex manually. I want it to work right after save links.

Comment: if you decrease the autocommit time under 10000 ms YES! with this config and a dual core / 2GB server and solr core < 5 millions of docs NO ! :)

Comment: I just tested it, still need to run sunspot:reindex =(

Comment: altered the response see : UPDATE 6/06 9H41 BRT