# Sunspot. Solr not searching any changes (create/update)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot-rails

I'm using sunspot_rails '~> 2.2' (Solr 5.3.1 1703449). 
When I create/update models I cannot find new changes and Solr admin panel for the target core doesn't show changes in `Last Modified`. But if I restart Solr directly I will be able to find by new changes and field `Last Modified` will also change.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [readme](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot#reindexing-objects):

> If you make a change to the object's "schema" (code in the searchable block), you must reindex all objects so the changes are reflected in Solr:
>
> `bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:reindex`

Also, according to [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ruby-sunspot/UD-fNxh1L-A) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3632278/sunspot-rails-not-re-indexing-model-after-save), `Sunspot.commit` which updates the Solr index is not automatically called if you're updating a model outside of a Rails request (for example, from the Rails console). You can manually call `Sunspot.commit` from the console to commit the changes to Solr.

Exectuting `bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:reindex` will also commit your changes.

Comment: I do not change a schema. I figure out that my target Solr core not reloading. But for now I don't understand why.

Comment: When you say "create/update searchable models", you mean "create/update searchable models in the database", for example through your app's UI?